# How do I get the list of all group members?

Tags: 7, log-messages, group

I have created one group using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, then I added some members in that group. Now I want to get list of all members in the group from some custom code.

How do I get the list of all group members?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Group module API](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/group.api.php).

```
$group->getMemberCount()
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? For example, how do you get $group to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a view using the Views UI, then export the view, and integrate that exported View in your custom code.

For the actual view, you should create a view of "***Group Memberships***", and optionally add a filter by Group ID (=`gid`).

For an example of such view, refer to my answer to "[How to add a column to the list of group members or create a Views equivalent of it?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219277/how-to-add-a-column-to-the-list-of-group-members-or-create-a-views-equivalent-of/219626#219626)", which includes a view (in export format), which should be pretty close to what you're asking for.