# How to add a column to the list of group members or create a Views equivalent of it?

Tags: 7, views, group

I use the "[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)" module and I want to add a column "Email Address" on the page that lists the members of the groups (I want to put this "Email" column between the column "member name" and the column "statut").

This page is not a view, it is the page that comes with the module, and which is located at `/group/gid/member` (with `gid` the id of the group). Here is a screenprint of it:

[image]

As an alternative (if adding such Email column on that page is too difficult or impossible), I want to create a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) page (to replace the module's member page). This view page should be identical (or as close as possible) to the screenshot above.

Here is a screenprint of the view I created so far:

[image]

And here is an export of this view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_membres';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'group_membership';
$view->human_name = 'Membres';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'views_bootstrap_table_plugin_style';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Groupe gid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['field'] = 'group';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Utilisateur uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Champ: Groupe : Titre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'group';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Nom */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Courriel */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Group role */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['id'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['field'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['label'] = 'Rôles';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'membres';
$translatables['group_membres'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Membres'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Groupe'),
  t('Utilisateur'),
  t('Titre'),
  t('Nom d\'utilisateur'),
  t('Courriel'),
  t('Statut de membre'),
  t('Rôles'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

My questions about this view:

- How to add the "Actions" column with links ?
- How to add filters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this updated version of your view (in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) export format, which you should be to import in your own site):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_members';
$view->description = 'List of all members in a specific Group';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'group_membership';
$view->human_name = 'Group Members';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: Group membership: Group gid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['field'] = 'group';
/* Relationship: Group membership: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Field: Group: Group ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Group: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'group';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
/* Field: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Field: Group membership: Membership status */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
/* Field: Group membership: Group role */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['id'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['field'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['label'] = 'Rôles';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['id'] = 'nothing_3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['label'] = 'View';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['text'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = 'Modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/edit?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['id'] = 'nothing_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['label'] = 'Annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['text'] = 'annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/cancel?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['id'] = 'nothing_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['label'] = 'Metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['text'] = 'metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/metadata';
/* Contextual filter: Group: Group ID */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['title'] = 'Members of the group with Group Id = %1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['validate']['type'] = 'numeric';
/* Filter criterion: Group membership: Membership status */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['label'] = 'Membership status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'group/%/memberlist';
```

Some more details about the changes in this view:

- I changed the machine name of it (to `group_members`), to avoid overwriting a same named view if you try to import this view.
- I changed the "`style_plugin`" to a standard "table" (to not have to depend on that bootstrap-variation, feel free to change that again).
- I added 2 fields that are "excluded from display", ie: the Group id (`gid`) and User id (`uid`). That way I can use their tokens in URLs in other fields I added afterwards.
- I added the fields (with appropriate links) for "Modifier", "Annuler" and "Metadata". For each of those fields I used the "rewrite results" technique.
- Note that I also added a similar "View"-link, since in your original view the links for users point to `user/uid` (which is not what matches with the orginal screenprint you started from ...).
- And I added an (exposed) filter for "Membership status".

Apart from the changes detailed above, I also included these enhancements (which I recommend you to also include):

- Add a **contextual filter** to specify the group ID for which the members should be shown.
- Adapt the **path** of this view to `/group/%/memberlist` (I couldn't use `/group/%/member` because that path is already used by the Group module). The `%` in this path is to be replaced by the group Id you want to show its members for. And if you want to see a list of members for **all** groups together, then just use `/group/all/memberlist`.
- Add a **title** like "Members of the group with Group Id = x" (with x = the selected group id).
- Limit **access** to the results of this view. The view in your question does not have any access restrictions. So I restricted (within "Page settings") the access to something with "Role", and selected as role "Administrator". Without that, even an anonymous user who knows the path to get access to this view can see a list of all group members, including there eMail IDs ... However, as delivered by the Group module, a path like `/group/gid/member` (with `gid` equal to some group id) cannot be accessed by an anonymous user.

With that, I think ... I'm ***done***.

PS (1 more recommendation to further improve it): use the [DataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) module to change the table-display to a ***dataTables*** display (try it, you'll love it ... especially if you have a high number of views results).

Comment: :-) Thank you it works but lacks the mass operations as in the original page.

Comment: @Mathieu about the mass Operations: if you make it a VBO view, and then combine that with Rules components, pretty sure you could come up with the equivalent of that also. You think I should create a new question about that, and add my own answer/solution also? Or you know how to do that yourself?